# Change database context through variable

Tags: database, t-sql

How can I use a variable as db context?

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[prName] (@dbname varchar(25)) as
begin
use master
some sql
<!--  I need to use master for some functions stored in master -->


use @dbname

exec('SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE [TABLE_CATALOG] = '+@dbname+' and TABLE_NAME=table123')

end

GO
```

Thanks

Comment: When user down votes a question without even giving reason in comments, it tells something about the user!!

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx).  You appear to have added a space between the dots and the table name.

Comment: its interesting that INFORMATION_SCHEMA needs the db context event though we specify TABLE_CATALOG! I think this its weird as we need to pass db name two times!

Comment: @user219628 what exactly are you trying to do?  You keep editing your question. Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: sorry for making multiple edits and thanks for your help. I am trying to write a procedure that will take db name as input and will perform Ltrim(Rtrim) on each column of particular table. For this I need to build a string like this           SELECT 'UPDATE '+@schema+'..'+@@table+' set '+column_name+' = Ltrim(Rtrim('+column_name+')' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE [TABLE_CATALOG] = @@dbname and TABLE_NAME = @@tablename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use the following:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[prName] (@dbname varchar(25)) as
begin
   exec('select top 5 * from '+@dbname+'.yourSchema.yourTable')
end
```

The `USE` statement is not allowed in a stored procedure.  If you are passing in the database name, then you do not need the `USE` statement, the database name will be included in your sql query.

Edit: Based on your edit that you need to access items in master, then all you need to do is execute your sql, specifying the need of `master` just use fully qualified sql.

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[prName] (@dbname varchar(25)) as
begin

    select * from master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

    exec('select top 5 * from '+@dbname+'.yourSchema.yourTable')
end
```

Comment: First dot is for the schema name.  Second dot is database name.  You look to be a dot short.